# Contradiction in Abbott's Understanding Analysis or my confusion?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Here are two statements that the textbook considers:

(1) For any two real numbers $a, b$

$$a \leq b \quad iff \quad a < b + \epsilon, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0$$

(2) Given an upper bound $s$ of a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R},$

$$s = \operatorname{sup}A \quad iff \quad \exists a \in A \quad s.t. \quad s - \epsilon < a, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0.$$

However, is it not the case that, by the first statement, if

$$s - \epsilon < a, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0,$$

then

$$s \leq a.$$

However, as $s$ is given to be an upper bound of the set $A,$ it is also the case that

$$s \geq a.$$

Therefore, it is necessarily the case that

$$s = a.$$

However, it is obviously not "necessarily" the case that the supremum of a set $A$ must be included in that set $A$ (that is, that the supremum of a set $A$ must be equal to some number in that set $A$).

Where am I confused? Or, where is Abbott confused?

Comment: the $a$ you pick depends on $\epsilon$, your order of quantifiers is wrong and what is confusing you, I think

Comment: (2) as written is incorrect. For example, if $A = (0,1)$ and $s = 1$, then $s = \sup A$ even though there is no $a \in A$ satisfying the condition. Are you sure you have correctly transcribed what Abbott has written?

Comment: I should specify, I meant the $a$ you pick in $(2)$

Comment: Verbatim: Assume $s \in R$ is an upper bound for a set $A \subseteq R.$ Then, $s = sup A$ iff, for every choice of $\epsilon > 0,$ there exists an element $a \in A$ satisfying $s - \epsilon < a.$ I did modify it, but I thought I did so in a way that did not change the meaning of the statement.

Comment: @Bungo What about $a = 1$ ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas $a=1$ is not an element of $A=(0,1)$.

Comment: @Bungo In my first read, I misread the set as $\{0,1\}$.Thank for the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt to rephrase Abbott resulted in an ambiguous statement:

$$s = \sup A \quad \mathrm{iff} \quad \exists a \in A \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \quad s - \epsilon < a, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0.$$

Does this mean
$$s = \sup A \quad \mathrm{iff} \quad ((\exists a \in A \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \quad s - \epsilon < a), \quad \forall \epsilon > 0), \tag1$$

or does it mean
$$s = \sup A \quad \mathrm{iff} \quad (\exists a \in A \quad \mathrm{s.t.} \quad (s - \epsilon < a, \quad \forall \epsilon > 0))? \tag2$$

Indeed $(2)$ would be incorrect in this context, because it is indeed equivalent to
$s = \sup A \iff (\exists a \in A:s \leq a).$
Note that it is true that $\sup A \leq \max A$ when $\max A$ exists (that is, when $A$ has a greatest element), but the idea of the supremum is that it is defined even when $A$ does not have a greatest element.

But $(1)$ is OK (apart from the fact that is an abominable mangling of the notation of predicate logic).
Note that if we write
$$a \leq b \iff (\forall \epsilon > 0 : a < b + \epsilon),$$
we fix the numbers $a$ and $b$ first, and *then* we say that a certain inequality involving those two already-chosen numbers must be true for
every value of $\epsilon$ that we might put in that inequality.
But in the right-hand side of $(1),$ which (more conventionally written) is
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists a \in A : s - \epsilon < a,$$
the $\forall$ symbol means the rest of the formula has to be evaluated for every possible positive value of $\epsilon,$
but each time we choose $\epsilon$ first and *then* say something about $a$ and $s.$
The way this works when there is no greatest element in $A$ is that we are allowed to choose different values of $a$ for different values of $\epsilon,$
and indeed we will have to do so.